# Count DISTINCT new values over time (SQL)

Tags: sql

Here's the data:

```
Date       | id 
-------------------
01/01/2020 | A
01/01/2020 | A
01/01/2020 | B
01/01/2020 | A
02/01/2020 | A
02/01/2020 | B
02/01/2020 | C
02/01/2020 | D
03/01/2020 | A
03/01/2020 | E
```

I want to be able to get the count of NEW unique values by month, so for example the output should be:

```
Date       | cnt_new_id 
-------------------
01/01/2020 | 2
02/01/2020 | 2
03/01/2020 | 1
```

As there are 2 unique values in January, 2 new unique values added in February (C & D) and 1 new unique value added in March (E). Thus, I want it to compare to the previous months and only count the newly added values (never recount values appearing in previous months).

How would I do this using SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Date/time functions vary radically among databases.  But the idea is pretty simple.  Use two levels of aggregation.  First get the earliest date for each id.  Then aggregate by month:

```
select extract(year from min_date), extract(month from min_date), count(*)
from (select id, min(date) as min_date
      from t
      group by id
     ) id
group by extract(year from min_date), extract(month from min_date);
```

Note:  This returns the year and date as separate columns.  The exact syntax for returning the first day of the month varies by database.